# Assigning a value for a property inside the set method

Tags: c#, properties

The code below causes StackOverflow error (As expected). However, I want to be able to set the value of this variable inside the set method. Is there a way to do this ?

```
public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return IsAvailable;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorAvailable;
            IsAvailable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorNotAvailable;
            IsAvailable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need backing field for property value

Comment: Your `get`-Attempt will cause a `Stackoverflow`-exception due to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a backing field:

```
private bool _isAvailable;

public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return _isAvailable;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorAvailable;
            _isAvailable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorNotAvailable;
            _isAvailable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: The code can be shortened considerably:

```
private bool _isAvailable;

public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return _isAvailable;
    }

    set
    {
        this.Shape.BrushColor = value ? ColorAvailable : ColorNotAvailable;
        _isAvailable = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see thanks! By the way, is using underscores a naming convention for backing fields ?

Comment: @Cemre: It is one of the two wide spread naming conventions, yes. The other is to not use the underscore or anything else, i.e. `isAvailable`, just like for a local variable or parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your property should encapsulate a private field and that should be set in the Setter, not the property.

```
private bool _IsAvailable; //private field
public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return _IsAvailable;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorAvailable;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorNotAvailable;
        }
        _IsAvailable = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backing field:

```
private bool _IsAvailable;
public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return _IsAvailable;
    }

    set
    {
        this.Shape.BrushColor = value ? ColorAvailable : ColorNotAvailable;
        _IsAvailable = value;
    }
}
```

[**Automatic vs Explicit Properties**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/14/automatic-vs-explicit-properties.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a private member `private bool _isAvailable` and store your flag there.

```
public bool IsAvailable 
{
get
{
    return _isAvailable;
}

set
{
    if (value)
    {
        this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorAvailable;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Shape.BrushColor = ColorNotAvailable;
    }
    _isAvailable = value;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use a backing field. But if you do not want to use backing field and sure that `this.Shape.BrushColor` will not be not set anywhere else you can do something (ugly) like:

```
public bool IsAvailable 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Shape.BrushColor == ColorAvailable;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Shape.BrushColor = value  ? ColorAvailable : ColorNotAvailable;               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially IsAvailable is the property not, as @Cemre correctly says, an underlying, (backing), field such as;

```
private bool _isAvailable;
```

I would also look at reducing the verbosity where, for instance, '(value == true)' is the same as 'if (value)', and setting value of the underlying field outside of the if...else and only on one line. In this way the above could be reduced to;

```
set
{
    this.Shape.BrushColor = value?ColorAvailable:ColorNotAvailable;
    _isAvailable = false;
}
```